# Immediately read data from a DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ToolStripComboBox that I populate using a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = Program.DB.GetView("myview");
cbInfo.ComboBox.DataSource = dt;
cbInfo.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
```

a little further in the same method, I want to read the items in `cbInfo`:

```
someinfo = (int)cbInfo.ComboBox.Items[0];
```

but this info doesn't seem to be available (an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown). How can I read the info, as soon as it available?

Comment: `cbInfo.ComboBox.Items[0]` ?

Comment: @Bolu no same problem. It seems like the data loading isn't done on the main thread.

Comment: What happens if you call [cbInfo.Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.invalidate.aspx) before?

Comment: DataTable contains data or rows?

Comment: @BartFriederichs why does `cbInfo` have `Items`? as `Bolu` suggested, you should edit your question to change it to `cbInfo.ComboBox`

Comment: Sorry. cbInfo is a `ToolStripComboBox`, which appears to have `Items`. I'll update my question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Invalidate()` has no effect.

Comment: Why not read the data source itself? `someinfo = (int)((DataTable)cbInfo.ComboBox.DataSource).Rows[0][0];`

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian `DataTable` has a few rows of data. The whole works fine, except that I want to read an item just after I created the combobox.

Comment: try calling cbInfo.RefreshItems()

Comment: @ShadowWizard that enabled me to do what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Post some sample which reproduces the problem

Comment: @Bart cheers, posted this as answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on the items might not be a good idea.

Better approach would be to take the data from the source, e.g.:

```
someinfo = (int)((DataTable)cbInfo.ComboBox.DataSource).Rows[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the selected index value on the combo box after you have loaded the data into it and then slecting cbinfo.comboboc.selectedItem

The syntax will be slightly different, but it should work and read the data from each item in the combo box as it is selected.

Comment: I can't set `SelectedItem`, as the `ComboBox` has no items yet.

Comment: Then you can't execute 
    someinfo = (int)cbInfo.ComboBox.Items[0];

Until you have loaded the items. Have you checked that the datatable is being populated?

Comment: Which is entirely my point .... there is data after this method is done, but not inside the method. The `DataTable` is nicely filled though.

Comment: Just seen your comment, apologies....

Have you set as the value member? Failing that, what if you call a sub method for retrieveing the value?

cbInfo.ComboBox.ValueMember = "someValue";